# Efficient access to data based on several fields

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++03

I have to store and work with the position of several elements in a file. Each element is located at a defined position in the file (line index, word index in the line). Each element is uniquely defined by an ID stored as a string.

I store this information in a map like this :

```
typedef std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t> LineColumn;
typedef std::map<std::string,LineColumn> ElementLineColumn;
ElementLineColumn element_line_column;
```

This is efficient to access to the position for each element (I do it in several parts of my algorithm).

But, this is not useful to read all the elements in the file. To do that, I duplicate the information in another map like this :

```
typedef std::map<std::size_t,std::string> ColumnElement;
typedef std::map<std::size_t,ColumnElement> LineColumnElement;
LineColumnElement line_column_element;
```

Where `line_column_element[element_line_column[key].first][element_line_column[key].second] == key`

This second storage is more useful to go through all the elements in the same order than stored in the file.

**My question : is there some intelligent structures in C++03/boost able to give an efficient access by both line/col indices and IDs without having to duplicate ?**

*Note : I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason with old compilers.*

Comment: Have you considered [Boost Multi-Index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are looking for is [BiMap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

A map that goes two ways.